# In general, should a PHP cookie name variables be held in its own variable

Tags: php, cookies

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
gives the following example:

```
<?php
$value = 'something from somewhere';

setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```

In general, is this the right way to do it, or when looking at good php code in general would you rather/normally see this:

```
<?php
$value = 'something from somewhere';
$cookie_name = 'TestCookie';

setcookie($cookie_name, $value);
setcookie($cookie_name, $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie($cookie_name, $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```

I know this is an open ended question, but I'm new to php and I want to know why you would do it either way.  Or is it pure user preference?

Comment: Pure user preference.

Comment: This is primarily an issue of preference. That being said, this is a valid question, but not for StackOverflow. Please consider checking out [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead for answers to such questions.

Comment: I'll give a short answer here, however: By not using a variable, every use of `"TestCookie"` is what we refer to as a "magic string", or a string that has no context associated with it whatsoever. These are usually bad because it can be difficult to remember or track down what that string is for, and if you need to change it then it can become expensive and risky to change every single instance. Recommended is to store within a variable. In this case, I would even recommend defining a _constant_ for it, e.g. `define("TEST_COOKIE", "TestCookie");`. Then you can do `setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, ...);`

Comment: that's what i was thinking, but in the examples I've seen, they usually/always use the "Magic String" method. Thanks.